# PHP header not working for Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, jquery, iis, upload, cross-domain

I am using the [jQuery File Upload plugin by Blueimp](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) to upload images to a server.  The problem is, the sending server is `admin.example.com`, and the receiving server where the images are stored is on `www.example.com`.  Same domain, different subdomain.

I followed the [instructions here on setting up cross-domain uploads](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Cross-domain-uploads#cross-site-xmlhttprequest-file-uploads), and everything seems to be correct as far as code, but when I try to upload the images, I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/upload/. Origin http://admin.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The upload folder does have read and write permissions.

I'm going to post my code below-if anyone can show me how to fix this, please let me know.  I had asked about this before and was going to try some other solutions (iframe uploads and ftp file moving).  Neither of these will be best for my situation, and it would be easiest if I could just do it this way...

**RECEIVING SERVER**

```
index.php

<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://admin.example.com');  //I have also tried the * wildcard and get the same response
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
?>
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    require('UploadHandler.php');
    $upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
```

**SENDING SERVER**

```
main.js

$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: 'http://admin.example.com/upload/',
        disableImageResize: false,
        dropZone: $('#dropzone'),
        imageMaxWidth: 1800,
        imageMaxHeight: 1800,
    });
});
```

Again I've tried the iframe file upload, so please don't suggest it unless you can give me full working code...

I have also tried `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` but get the same error...I'm trying to get this finished by the weekend so I'd appreciate any help I can get. :)

Thanks!

EDIT: here's the response headers for the failed OPTIONS request

```
Allow:OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Content-Length:0
Date:Tue, 27 Aug 2013 15:08:29 GMT
Public:OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: Look at the requests your browser makes. It will first do an OPTIONS request (not GET or POST). Check if your server replies with the correct headers. The _real_ request doesn't actually need the CORS headers.

Comment: Seems he is handling OPTIONS

Comment: @FritsvanCampen see my edit above, don't see anything for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`...

Comment: Well, I don't see the CORS headers so make sure your script gets called for the `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen so I need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to the headers???

Comment: Yes, but your script does that already, I'm guessing it's not getting called properly.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen sorry, getting confused....what should I do to fix it?

Comment: I don't know. For some reason IIS decides not to call your script. I don't know anything about IIS and how it handles OPTIONS request, I expect it would just call your script but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen So is there something with the IIS server that needs to be done? I just got administrative access to the server, so I'm still getting used to it, but I can contact the IT person.

Comment: I don't know. I have no experience with IIS. I had no problems when I made this with Apache.

Comment: does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 26):

I use this headers and its work for me

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
```

Comment: on the index.php file?

Comment: Yes. 
Also, try to place after  "require('UploadHandler.php');"

Comment: and do not forget to restart the server

Comment: tried it, still doesn't work...I guess I'll just stick with the FTP upload.  I do have another question with `web.config` files, maybe you could help with that? (http://stackoverflow.com/q/18489657/636848)

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, I still get the error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Aitem Not sure if you're still around, and I understand that you wrote that comment 5 years ago, but could you substantiate what you mean? There is no need to restart the *apache* server so that a *php* script be able to set headers. Restarting the server is not something that is related to the functions in this answer.

Comment: why use " * " symbol? it's insecure, i think is only needed to one site url, not for all as well

Answer (score 1):

I would try to set this on the web.config since you're operating on an IIS server:

https://gist.github.com/corydeppen/3518666

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <!-- allowing all-->
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to **re-save the PHP file using UTF-8 encoding**. Apparently the original text file (that I copied into place and overwrote for the quick test) used was using some other funky encoding.